# What is $\mathbb{P}^1-\{0,1,\infty\}$ and why it is interesting？

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I found it in this note http://swc.math.arizona.edu/aws/1998/98BuiumLN.pdf

Of course, it is the projective line minus three points. But I don't believe it is as simple as it looks like. What can we talk about it？

Comment: What's interesting depends on what you're interested in.  If you're interested in a particular generalization of the abc conjecture, then the paper you linked to contains the answer to your question.  If you're interrested in something else, we can't answer this question until you tell us what that something else is.  (Just as we wouldn't be able to answer the question "Why is the number 7 interesting?" without some additional context.)

Comment: $\mathbb{P}^1$-{0,1,$\infty$ } is a example for me. I want to know the geometry and arithmetic about it.

Comment: If you're open to arithmetic then you had better read Deligne's [Le Groupe Fondamental de la Droite Projective Moins Trois Points](http://www.math.ias.edu/files/deligne/GaloisGroups.pdf). For some people this was a life-changing paper. I could try to say why but I think [Ellenberg will do a better job](https://quomodocumque.wordpress.com/2009/07/24/le-groupe-fondamental-de-la-droite-projective-moins-trois-points-is-now-online/).

Comment: Trivial remark: $\mathbb{P}^1 \setminus \{0,1,\infty\} = \mathrm{Spec}(k[T,T^{-1},(T-1)^{-1}])$.

Answer (score 1):

The open Riemann surface $X := \mathbb C \setminus \{0, 1\} = \mathbb P^1 \setminus \{\infty, 0, 1\}$ is an interesting object from the viewpoint of complex analysis: It is a simple but non-trivial example of an open Riemann surface which is strictly negative curved. Notably, $X$ is an open complete hyperbolic manifold.

For the proof, one may consider the universal covering $\lambda: \mathbb H \longrightarrow X$ with the elliptic modular function $\lambda$, see the book "Complex analysis" of Ahlfors. On the upper half plane $\mathbb H$ the metric with value at $x+iy\in \mathbb H$

$$ds^2 = \frac {2dz d\overline z} {A*y^2}$$

has curvature $-A$ and is invariant under the action of $\lambda$. Hence it induces a metric on $X$ which is strictly negative curved. The latter fact implies $X$ being hyperbolic.

Holomorphic mappings into hyperbolic manifolds have interesting properties. See the book "Hyperbolic manifolds and holomorphic mappings" by S. Kobayashi.

Comment: A nice application of this is the original proof by Picard of its Little Theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem